# How to see a list of new non-version controlled files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

So I add new files to my project. At this point IntelliJ pops up a dialog asking me if I'd like to add these files to git/mercurial/svn etc.

I will always say **No** at this point because until I've fleshed the files out a little, perhaps got them to work with some context, perhaps decided to rename them, I'm not happy to add these new files to version control. Even if I can still rollback the 'add', I have to bare in mind the nuts and bolts of the underlying system. It's safer simply not to do it.

Now I'm ready to commit, I bring up the commit dialog box and the new files are nowhere to be found! If I go on a scouting expedition for them, I can add them individually from project files but this is error-prone.

How do I automatically get a list of all my new files which I previously delayed adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, under the changes tab. I was looking for it only under the version control context menu from project files.